# How to split a big image into multiple textures

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

Let's assume I have a big image whose size is 2560*800 and format is RGBA.
I'd like to this big image to 2 textures whose size are 1280*800.

The simple, but stupid, way is m

```
#define BPP_RGBA    4
int* makeNTexturesFromBigRgbImage(uint8_t *srcImg,
                               Size srcSize,
                               uint32_t numTextures,
                               uint32_t texWidth,
                               uint32_t texHeigh) {
    int i, h, srcStride;
    uint8_t *pSrcPos, *pDstPos;

    int [] texIds = new int[numTextures];
    srcStride = srcSize.w*BPP_RGBA;

    glGenTextures(numTextures, texIds);

    for (i=0; i<numTexures; i++) {
        uint8_t *subImageBuf = alloc(texWidth*texHeight*BPP_RGBA);
        pSrcPos = srcImg+(texWidth*BPP_RGBA)*i
        pDstPos = subImageBuf;
        for (h=0; h<texHeight; h++) {
            memcpy(pDstPos, pSrcPos, texWidth*BPP_RGBA)
            pSrcPos += srcStride;
            pDstPos += (texWidth*BPP_RGBA);
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, subImageBuf);
        free(subImageBuf);
    }
}
```

But, as I mentioned above, this approach is very stupid.

So, I'd like to know the best way that DOES NOT copy operation on CPU like above.
Is it possible with only openGL APIs.

For example, is it possible?

```
Step 1. Make a texture, 2560*800, with an big image.
Step 2. Make 2 textures, 1280*800, from the texture in 1.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may be looking for something like glPixelStore with GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH.

Comment: Is glCopyImageSubData what you are looking for?

Comment: glCopyImageSubData Is supprted in opengl 4.3 or later. I'm using 2.0 (or 3.0).

Comment: @Robinson As I know, GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH is related to the alignment. Isn't it?

Comment: which OpenGL(ES) version are you targetting?  @Robinson's suggestion should work in OpenGL2 and up (and maybe earlier), and OpenGLES3 (but not OpenGLES2, at least without extensions).

Comment: I'm working on an Android device and opengles version supported by the target is 0x30002 (=199610)

Comment: If your source data is from outside of GL, I'm not sure it matters whether you make one large glTexImage or two smaller ones - the amount of data copied is the same in both cases.

Comment: ... and second question is why do you need two textures? Why not just change your texture coordinates?

Comment: Source data comes from external camera module, which is sending the frames that 4 camera source are integrated together. That is, camera module output is a frame = "camera 1 + camera 2 + camera 3 + camera 4". I'd like to the frame into 4 camera frames again in my application and each frame is displayed in with projected position. But I'd like to want to use 1 program (= 1 vertex shader + 1 fragment shader).